# Prove $x\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}} + y\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{y}} + z\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{z}} = 0 $

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$$x\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}} + y\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{y}} + z\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{z}} = 0 $$

give $u = f (\frac{x}{a}.\frac{y}{b},\frac{z}{c})$.

I tried assuming $\frac{x}{a} = l ,\frac{y}{b}= m , \frac{z}{c} = n $ and applied chain rule but couldnot get to result

Comment: For a general function $f$ this is not true. Are you sure you've written the problem correctly, and there is no additonal assumptions about $f$?

Comment: This statement is wrong in general. You have to give more details about the exercise.

Comment: @J.Deff I can't find your question in the link you posted.

Comment: @user10354138 Me neither

Comment: link for pdf f ile

Comment: @J.Deff We have search through the entire 7 pages and can't find the question.  Which question number is it?

Comment: sorry this is file

Comment: https://www.examrace.com/d/pdf/da096757/IAS-Mains-Mathematics-1996.pdf

Comment: Q uestion no 5 part a

Comment: That isn't what you posted.  you have these mysterious $a,b,c$.

Comment: oh yes ...in my assignment it iswritten wrong then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conclusion is incorrect.

Note that $x\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+y\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}+z\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}=0$ is $(\mathbf{r}\cdot\nabla)u=0$, i.e., $u$ is constant along each ray $\mathbf{r}=t\mathbf{v}$, $t>0$.  So the general solution on $\mathbb{R}^3-\{(0,0,0)\}$ is $u(\mathbf{r})=f(\mathbf{r}/r)$, where $f$ is a differentiable function on $S^2$, which cannot be extended to $(0,0,0)$ unless $f$ is constant.

---

With the corrected question and the correct way of implication, it is just the chain rule.

If $u=f(x/y,y/z,z/x)$, then
\begin{align*}\require{color}
x\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}
&=x\left[(\partial_1 f)\left(\frac{x}{y},\frac{y}{z},\frac{z}{x}\right)\cdot\frac1y+(\partial_3f)\left(\frac{x}{y},\frac{y}{z},\frac{z}{x}\right)\cdot\frac{-z}{x^2}\right]\\
&={\color{red}(\partial_1 f)\left(\frac{x}{y},\frac{y}{z},\frac{z}{x}\right)\cdot\frac{x}y}-{\color{green}(\partial_3f)\left(\frac{x}{y},\frac{y}{z},\frac{z}{x}\right)\cdot\frac{z}x}
\end{align*}
and similarly
\begin{align*}
y\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} &={\color{blue}
(\partial_2 f)\left(\frac{x}{y},\frac{y}{z},\frac{z}{x}\right)\cdot\frac{y}z}-{\color{red}(\partial_1f)\left(\frac{x}{y},\frac{y}{z},\frac{z}{x}\right)\cdot\frac{x}y}
\\
z\frac{\partial u}{\partial z} &={\color{green}
(\partial_3 f)\left(\frac{x}{y},\frac{y}{z},\frac{z}{x}\right)\cdot\frac{z}x}-{\color{blue}(\partial_2f)\left(\frac{x}{y},\frac{y}{z},\frac{z}{x}\right)\cdot\frac{y}z}
\end{align*}
So adding gives the equation
$$
x\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+y\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}+z\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}=0.
$$

Answer (score 1):

The function $u=f(x/y,y/z,z/x)$ is homogeneous of degree $0$. According to the Euler’s theorem on homogeneous functions the given relation is true.

Details: The function $u(x,y,z)=f(x/y,y/z,z/x)$ is homogenous of degree $0$:
$$u(tx,ty,tz)=f(tx/ty,ty/tz,tz/tx)=f(x/y,y/z,z/x)=t^0u(x,y,z).$$
Hence, according to Euler's theorem:
$$xu_x+yu_y+zu_z=0\cdot u(x,y,z)=0.$$
Reference: [Euler's Homogeneous Function Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulersHomogeneousFunctionTheorem.html)

Comment: Can you elaborate your first line

Comment: is n't definition of homogenous ffucntion is $x^n f(y \x, z\x )$

Comment: Definition of homogenous function is given in the beginning of the referenced article: $f(tx,ty)=t^nf(x,y)$ is homogenous of degree $n$. Here $t$ is just a scaling factor.